# sum from array until a given value is reached.

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, random

I have several numpy arrays with values, that look as follows:

```
po_freq1 = [0.01408451 0.05633803 0.14084507 0.02816901 0.01408451 0.01408451
0.05633803 0.05633803 0.01408451 0.01408451 0.01408451 0.01408451
0.02816901 0.07042254 0.01408451 0.01408451 0.04225352 0.11267606
0.04225352 0.01408451 0.04225352 0.02816901 0.01408451 0.04225352
0.05633803 0.01408451 0.01408451 0.01408451]
```

my goal is to chose randomly some values from my array and sum these values until a given value for example 0.90 is reached.  Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Using a simple `while` loop should do the job. Don't overthink it with iterators or accumulators and stuff.

Comment: One way: keep extracting random value from array, and add it to a variable that holds the partial sum, until the sentinel value is reached. Anyway, please show us what you've tried.

Comment: What did you try already?

Comment: By "reached", do you mean "exceeded"?  Are duplicate picks permitted (other than the duplicates built into your list)?

Comment: That sounds like a pretty nonsensical task in itself. Do you have to do anything alongside that operation? Remember which elements you picked? Minimise the difference to the target?

Comment: I mean exceed, and yes duplicate picks are permitted, cause each value stands for a certain population frequency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using random package and while loop

```
import random
po_freq1 = [0.01408451, 0.05633803, 0.14084507, 0.02816901, 0.01408451, 0.01408451,
0.05633803, 0.05633803, 0.01408451, 0.01408451, 0.01408451, 0.01408451,
0.02816901, 0.07042254, 0.01408451, 0.01408451, 0.04225352, 0.11267606,
0.04225352, 0.01408451, 0.04225352, 0.02816901, 0.01408451, 0.04225352,
0.05633803, 0.01408451, 0.01408451, 0.01408451]

sumv = 0.
while sumv<0.9: sumv += random.choice(po_freq1)
print (sumv)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `cumsum` and `argmin`, shuffle the array to make the selection random:

```
arr = np.array([0.87868619, 0.08184167, 0.01502171, 0.96840561, 0.31431041,
       0.531577  , 0.66069971, 0.1204876 , 0.9684556 , 0.81405872,
       0.48118081, 0.91681978, 0.15017044, 0.50540813, 0.11617046,
       0.01897202, 0.1894475 , 0.94660911, 0.46030856, 0.04641654])
np.random.shuffle(arr)
```

For a threshold of `5` for example:

```
>>> (np.cumsum(arr)<=5).argmin()
11
```

This provides you with the index where you should *stop* summing.  This will be faster than a while loop, since the operations are vectorized.

```
In [38]: np.sum(arr[:11])
Out[38]: 4.15852117

In [39]: np.sum(arr[:12])
Out[39]: 5.126976770000001
```